# Python Pandas groupby limited cumulative sum

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements, cumsum

This is my dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'c1':[-1,-1,1,1,np.nan,1,1,1,1,1,np.nan,-1],\
        'c2':[1,1,1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,1,-1,1,np.nan]}

index = pd.date_range('2000-01-01','2000-03-20', freq='W')

df = pd.DataFrame(index=index, data=data)


>>> df
             c1   c2
2000-01-02 -1.0  1.0
2000-01-09 -1.0  1.0
2000-01-16  1.0  1.0
2000-01-23  1.0 -1.0
2000-01-30  NaN  1.0
2000-02-06  1.0  1.0
2000-02-13  1.0 -1.0
2000-02-20  1.0 -1.0
2000-02-27  1.0  1.0
2000-03-05  1.0 -1.0
2000-03-12  NaN  1.0
2000-03-19 -1.0  NaN
```

and this is a cumulative sum by month

```
df2 = df.groupby(df.index.to_period('m')).cumsum()

>>> df2
             c1   c2
2000-01-02 -1.0  1.0
2000-01-09 -2.0  2.0
2000-01-16 -1.0  3.0
2000-01-23  0.0  2.0
2000-01-30  NaN  3.0
2000-02-06  1.0  1.0
2000-02-13  2.0  0.0
2000-02-20  3.0 -1.0
2000-02-27  4.0  0.0
2000-03-05  1.0 -1.0
2000-03-12  NaN  0.0
2000-03-19  0.0  NaN
```

what I need more is to ignore the increment if it is more than 3 or less than 0, something like this function

```
def cumsum2(arr, low=-float('Inf'), high=float('Inf')):
    arr2 = np.copy(arr)
    sm = 0
    for index, elem in np.ndenumerate(arr):
        if not np.isnan(elem):
            sm += elem
            if sm > high:
                sm = high
            if sm < low:
                sm = low
        arr2[index] = sm
    return arr2
```

the desired result is

```
             c1   c2
2000-01-02  0.0  1.0
2000-01-09  0.0  2.0
2000-01-16  1.0  3.0
2000-01-23  2.0  2.0
2000-01-30  2.0  3.0
2000-02-06  1.0  1.0
2000-02-13  2.0  0.0
2000-02-20  3.0  0.0
2000-02-27  3.0  1.0
2000-03-05  1.0  0.0
2000-03-12  1.0  1.0
2000-03-19  0.0  1.0
```

I tried to use apply and lambda but doesn't work and it's slow for large dataframe.

```
df.groupby(df.index.to_period('m')).apply(lambda x: cumsum2(x, 0, 3))
```

What's wrong? Is there a faster way?

Comment: Is the issue still relevant? I wanted to suggest a working solution.

Comment: yes of course, any suggestions are welcome

Answer (score 2):

You can try `accumulate` from itertools and use a custom function to clip values between 0 and 3:

```
from itertools import accumulate

lb = 0  # lower bound
ub = 3  # upper bound

def cumsum2(dfm):
    def clip(bal, val):
        return np.clip(bal + val, lb, ub)
    return list(accumulate(dfm.to_numpy(), clip, initial=0))[1:]

out = df.fillna(0).groupby(df.index.to_period('m')).transform(cumsum2)
```

Output:

```
>>> out
             c1   c2
2000-01-02  0.0  1.0
2000-01-09  0.0  2.0
2000-01-16  1.0  3.0
2000-01-23  2.0  2.0
2000-01-30  2.0  3.0
2000-02-06  1.0  1.0
2000-02-13  2.0  0.0
2000-02-20  3.0  0.0
2000-02-27  3.0  1.0
2000-03-05  1.0  0.0
2000-03-12  1.0  1.0
2000-03-19  0.0  1.0
```

Comment: Thanks for your hint but I get 2 errors

TypeError: accumulate() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)

TypeError: Transform function invalid for data types

I try to update my modules.

Answer (score 1):

In such sophisticated case we can resort to [`pandas.Series.rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.rolling.html#pandas.Series.rolling) with window of size `2` piping each window to a custom function to keep each interim accumulation within a certain threshold:

```
def cumsum_tsh(x, low=-float('Inf'), high=float('Inf')):
    def f(w):
        w[-1] = min(high, max(low, w[0] if w.size == 1 else w[0] + w[1]))
        return w[-1]
    return x.apply(lambda s: s.rolling(2, min_periods=1).apply(f))

res = df.fillna(0).groupby(df.index.to_period('m'), group_keys=False)\
    .apply(lambda x: cumsum_tsh(x, 0, 3))
```

---

```
             c1   c2
2000-01-02  0.0  1.0
2000-01-09  0.0  2.0
2000-01-16  1.0  3.0
2000-01-23  2.0  2.0
2000-01-30  2.0  3.0
2000-02-06  1.0  1.0
2000-02-13  2.0  0.0
2000-02-20  3.0  0.0
2000-02-27  3.0  1.0
2000-03-05  1.0  0.0
2000-03-12  1.0  1.0
2000-03-19  0.0  1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried various solutions, for some reason the fastest is manipulating single columns of frames created by groupby.
This is the code if it can be useful to anyone

```
def cumsum2(frame, low=-float('Inf'), high=float('Inf')):
    for col in frame.columns:
        sm = 0
        xs = []
        for e in frame[col]:
            sm += e
            if sm > high:
                sm = high
            if sm < low:
                sm = low
            xs.append(sm)
        frame[col] = xs
    return frame

res = df.fillna(0).groupby(df.index.to_period('m'), group_keys=False)\
                                            .apply(cumsum2,0,3)
```